# Details tag with grid elements in summary and content

Tags: html, css, css-grid, display

I'm trying to make a grid layout work with the `details` tag, but I can't get the `summary` and content to appear on the same line.

```css
details > summary {
  list-style: none;
}

.accordion__content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.accordion__summary {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.g-col-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.g-col-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}
.g-col-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
.g-col-4 {
  grid-column: 4;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <div class="accordion__summary">
      <div class="g-col-1">Test1</div>
      <div class="g-col-2">Test2</div>
      <div class="g-col-3">Test3</div>
    </div>
  </summary>
  <div class="accordion__content">
    <div class="g-col-4">Test4</div>
  </div>
</details>
```

At first I tired to put the `display:grid` directly on the `details` tag and use `display:contents` on the `summary` tag, but apparently there is some hidden display property that can't be overridden.

Basically I want to place everything inside the `details` tag on the same grid.

I'm looking for a CSS-only solution.

Comment: I'm a bit worried by your HTML structure as divs are not allowed as elements of summary here. (According to both MDN and W3C validator).

Comment: @AHaworth Oh really. I was not aware of that ... I guess I'll just keep using the checkbox hack then ...

Answer (score 0):

While still using a duplicate grid, this seems to work.
Basically just bubble the grid columns to a wrapper grid containing the whole `details` tag.
When closed, just display a "fake" grid that looks the same as the wrapper one.

```css
.accordion {
  display: grid;
  --gridCols: 5em 5em 5em 5em;
  grid-template-columns: var(--gridCols);
}

details > summary {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--gridCols);
  list-style: none;
}

details {
  grid-column: 1 / -1; /* without this, auto will not work correctly */
}

details[open] {
  display: contents;
}
details[open] > summary {
  display: contents;
}



.g-col-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.g-col-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}
.g-col-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
.g-col-4 {
  grid-column: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <details>
    <summary>
      <span class="g-col-1">Test1</span>
      <span class="g-col-2">Test2</span>
      <span class="g-col-3">Test3</span>
    </summary>
    <div class="g-col-4">Test4</div>
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: This solves the problem as presented in the question, but the HTML is not legal (divs in summary element).

Comment: @AHaworth I updated the answer. There also was a problem with auto as I didn't specify the `details` width.